# Rename-Item with incremental numbers for files with the same name

Tags: powershell, pdf

I am trying to rename files using the output of another script that I ran.

To be specific, I am working with forms (.pdf) from polling stations. First, I used OCR to extract all the name of the polling stations. The output was saved in CSV form (where each line is old_name, new_name)

Now, I am trying to use these polling station names to rename the original form to its polling station name. Here is what I wrote:

```
$myHeader = echo oldName newName
Import-Csv C:\some_directory\new_name_list.txt -Header $myHeader | foreach {
    if (Test-Path -Path "C:\some_directory\*.pdf") { 
        Rename-Item $_.oldName $_.newName
    }
}

# newName is the polling station name
```

However, the problem is that there are multiple forms that belong to the same polling station. In this case the newname is the same. So, when I run the script, I get the error message

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

How can I make it so that the files with the same polling station be named something like

polling_station_name_001.pdf
polling_station_name_002.pdf
polling_station_name_003.pdf
…

I've looked at options with `for` or `%i++`, but I was wondering if there is a better solution that is more straightforward.

Comment: If you are looking to do this _before_ the first file in a group gets made I would suggest playing with the source data before your rename loop. You could use `group-object` to collect all the `newname`s that are going to be the same and edit them to have the incremental numbers. Using a `$i++` would be the simple way to track that.

Comment: Also your first few lines are odd. You have a header that is incorrectly assigned... supposed to be a string array I imagine `$myHeader= "oldName", "newName"`. I am guessing that there is a newline on the second line by accident.

Comment: @Matt `$myHeader = echo oldName newName` == `$myHeader = Write-Output 'oldName' 'newName'` == `$myHeader = 'oldName', 'newName'` ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Obviously not used to seeing it like that so now I get it thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's rather ... unconventional, so it took me a moment to realize, too. ^_^

Comment: @LotPings the logic is similar for that one. From the sounds of it though they want the increment to be present on all files in a group which you would have know before hand.

Comment: In the solutions, I find that the loop while (Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$i" + $_.Extension)
       $i++  
    }
could be avoided by using a hash table with as key file names and as value, the number of repetitions.